# javascript escape string

Tags: javascript

I have the following string:

> 'You've just created'

When I assign this string to a JavaScript variable, this is interpreted as 2 strings because there's a `'` character.

How can I escape it?

Comment: When you say ‘pass it to a variable’, what do you mean? Are you simply defining a static variable, or using server-side code to generate JavaScript code with the variable in it? If the latter, you should look at using a JSON encoder to create your JavaScript literals.

Comment: @bobince: hmm... I assumed the former when tidying up the question grammar, but now that you mention it, the issue could be the result of outputting unescaped strings from the server.

Comment: http://mothereff.in/js-escapes#1You%27ve%20just%20created

Answer (score 2):

In JS code blocks, use a backslash:

```
var text = 'You \'ve just created'
```

in JS inside HTML, use a HTML entity:

```
<a onclick='alert("You &apos;ve just created");'>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use either " or ' to quote a string, so you could do it this way:

```
"You've just created"
```

or you can use a \ to quote just one character:

```
'You\'ve just created'
```